# Some special characters are appended at the end of string

Tags: c, pointers

Below is the code to allocate some chunk of memory and and copies the string into the block.
Input is passed through the argument of the function and "str" is the allocated chunk of memory.

```
char *fun (char * input) {
size_t size= strlen(input);
char * str;

str = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * size);
memcpy(str, input , size);
return str;

}

int main(){

char * temp = "abcdef";

char * ret = fun(temp);

printf("%s",ret);

return 0;
}
```

```
When I executed this piece of code some special characters are appended at the end of this.
So the output looks like abcdef▼ 
Please suggest what went wrong.
```

Comment: Did you consider putting null '\0' in the end of string?

Comment: Oh yes I missed it I guess. I need to put that. Thanks.

Comment: Strings in C need to be NUL terminated. So you need to allocate and copy one more than the `strlen`. Or just call `strdup` (unless the task does not allow that).

Comment: @kaylum sure I will do it and try to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put null character in the end of the string to notify that its the end of it.

```
char *fun (char * input) {
  size_t size= strlen(input);
  char * str;

  str = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * (size+1));
  memcpy(str, input , size);
  str[size]='\0';

  return str;
}
```

Comment: I agree . It should be  (size +1 )

Comment: Done. Check now